# ERROR: Can not execute `setup.py` since setuptools is not available in the build environment

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, setup.py, python-packaging

I am trying to upload my python package to PyPi. I successfully uploaded my package to pypi but unable to install it.

Here is the PyPi link of my uploaded python package: [PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/PardhuEmailSender/0.1/)

It was uploaded successfully to PyPi. You can check my uploaded files in [GitHub](https://github.com/JavaHunt/PardhuEmailSender)

Now I am trying to download my package with results with an error seen below.
[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Cofb.png)

I don't where is wrong. I imported setuptools in my setup.py file

Comment: Your project can not have `email` in its dependencies (and does not need to), because [_`email`_ is part of Python's own standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.html). It does not need to be installed because it is always present. Same goes for [_`smtlib`_](https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html). You have to remove `email` and `smtplib` from the `install_requires` list in `setup.py`.